# Turn incoming call to a conference on BlackBerry

Tags: blackberry

I want to turn an incoming call into a conference call

My options:

1. When the user answers an incoming call, the app calls a second number, which I assume will put the first call on hold.  Instead of having a conference, the incoming call is dropped. The outgoing call is done in the same thread as the callConnected(int) method.
2. Same as above except the call is done in a separate thread with or without a delay before the call.

None of these two scenarios are working.  I have tried to hold the call and make the call on callHeld().  This didn't help either.